# syntax error, unexpected '$arr' (T_VARIABLE) ?? why this error

Tags: php

I am getting this error in php . can anyone help!!  it says

> unexpected '$arr' (T_VARIABLE)

. what is T_variable ??

```
<?php $d=date("D"); if ($d=="Fri") echo "Have a nice weekend!"; else echo "Have a nice day!"; 
    print "\nday is $d"; 

    $array = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5); foreach( $array as $value ) { echo "Value is $value <br />"; }

    print "\n associative arrays"


    $arr = array( 
                     "key1" => value1,
                     "key2"=> value2,
                     "key3"=> value3
                    );

        echo "printing out";

        //foreach($arr as $value)
         //echo "$value ";
    ?>
```

Comment: `E_SEMICOLON_MISSING_IN_LINE_BEFORE`

Comment: Use an ide to avoid typo errors like this one. (eclipse, netbeans, phpstorm are 3 in 1 million)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a semicolon.

```
print "...";
```

Comment: what is T_variable ??

Comment: It's the parser token for a variable.

Answer (score 0):

change line:

```
print "\n associative arrays"
```

to:

```
print "\n associative arrays";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add semicolon after

```
print "\n associative arrays";
```